# Open link with other browser from chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser

I have to put a link in my web application for going to other application but that other application was designed to use on IE only.

Is there any way to force my link to open that site in IE when my app was run in chrome.

Comment: What if IE is not available/installed in client machine?

Comment: Please assume that every client already install IE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a javascript link open up in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725645/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-javascript-link-open-up-in-ie)