# how can I open link from chrome in ie using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the function window.open that get url in javascript and open it in new tab, the site is in chrome and I need that the url will open in ie. is it possible?

I tryed to add "ie:" before the url.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you can't just run programs on the user machine with JS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725645/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-javascript-link-open-up-in-ie it is not possible unfortunately

Comment: No, this is not possible with JavaScript (Its doable if you have control of all the user machines, say in a corporate environment).

Comment: This isn't possible. The browser and OS will determine what application to use to open a link by default, and the user will control that. It is out of control of JS code.

Comment: what do you mean by "the site is in chrome" ?! Chrome and ie are just browsers, nothing more.

Comment: The best you can do is detect the browser, and say something like, "This site requires internet explorer to function properly, please open in Internet Explorer." ..

Comment: @ThomasK I think you spelt "thankfully" incorrectly :P

Comment: is it possible in c#?

Comment: In C# you can run any application on the machine that the C# is running on (eg a console app or a win-forms app).  Given this was asked as javascript/jquery, it's likely your c# would be running on the server (a web server) - so no, you can't run applications on a client's PC from a web server.